# Choreo Integration

Tags: ballerina, wso2-choreo

We are tying to develop a connector which will be used in one of our integrations using Choreo. But when trying to build in ballerina, got the following error:

```
[2022-09-02 17:20:39,741] SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - Java heap space 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
        at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:172)
        at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:633)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:392)
        at java.base/java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:122)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:590)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:707)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:713)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:713)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:713)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:713)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:721)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$27.write(TypeAdapters.java:655)
        at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.write(Streams.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString(JsonElement.java:316)
        at org.ballerinalang.observability.anaylze.DefaultObservabilitySymbolCollector.generateCanonicalJsonString(DefaultObserv
        at org.ballerinalang.observability.anaylze.DefaultObservabilitySymbolCollector.writeToExecutable(DefaultObservabilitySym
        at io.ballerina.projects.JarResolver.getJarFilePathsRequiredForExecution(JarResolver.java:107)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.emitExecutable(JBallerinaBackend.java:521)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.emit(JBallerinaBackend.java:206)
        at io.ballerina.cli.task.CreateExecutableTask.execute(CreateExecutableTask.java:97)
        at io.ballerina.cli.TaskExecutor.executeTasks(TaskExecutor.java:40)
        at io.ballerina.cli.cmd.BuildCommand.execute(BuildCommand.java:252)
        at io.ballerina.cli.launcher.Main$$Lambda$94/0x000000010016c040.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
```

I was still able to push this to the repo but the connector did not appear in the Choreo canvas. Any thoughts on how we can resolve this?

Comment: You check whether your code is optimized for high performance.

 1. Use local variables wherever possible.
 2. Make sure you select the correct object (EX: Selection between String, StringBuffer and StringBuilder)
 3. Use a good code system for your program(EX: Using static variables VS non-static variables)
 4. Try to move with multi THREADING

Comment: Cannot tell exactly the issue by just looking at the code. Can you show us the code that results in this exception?

Comment: I changed the yml file only to have the endpoint details I need and then build. Now it working. Earlier version had all the endpoint documentation, might be too large to process.
Thank you for your replies